# NFS World crashes and PC restarts automatically

Tags: technical-issues, need-for-speed-world

I've downloaded NFS World from official site and done the updates, however when I open the game at the lowest resolution and lowest texture at some point (after about 2-3 minutes) the game hangs and repeats last played sound (like drifting) and then carries on playing.

This repeats 3-4 times then my computer restarts automatically.

I've tried Heaven Benchmark and open hardware monitor and they reported about 90% GPU memory use!

I also tried Prime 95 torturing tests and reported 100% CPU usage (which is normal for that test) but people say that it should run for hours to heat up the CPU, but it heated up to 81 C in about 3 minutes.

My PC specs :

```
CPU        : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E4500 @ 2.20GHz
GPU        : Nvidia GeForce 7300 GS
Ram        : 2 X 1GB
OS         : Microsoft Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3 (build 2600)
Sound Card : Realtek High Definition Audio
```

---

**EDIT :**

a blue screen of death came today when it hanged:

[image: BSOD Error]

Comment: With the amount of heat you're generating I would suspect you don't have enough cooling or something is obstructing the airflow inside your case. Do you experience this issue in any other game or is it specifically Need for Speed: World that is causing this issue? Do you get a blue screen of death, or does it completely lock up and then reboot without a blue screen? Do you feel confident taking apart your PC and (carefully!) vacuuming any dust out of it, checking fans, reseating RAM, etc?

Comment: Based on that information, chances are extremely good your computer is overheating.  Might want to see if the CPU fan is working properly.

Comment: @pixel it doesn't produce too much heat (73 C max GPU,65 C max CPU),this issue comes with high quality games ,but world is the first which I experience with low quality,it doesn't show a blue screen it just reboots,I already did take apart my pc and cleaned everything

Comment: 65 degrees for a modern day CPU sounds crazy high.  For comparison, my computer idles at room temperature, and I can't get it to go above 40 degrees, unless I've let the fans get clogged with dust.

Comment: A computer suddenly restarting during high graphics games (and the summer) is usually a heating problem. So listen to pixel and fbueckert, they are probably right. I also had this problem a lot during a hot summer.

Comment: One spec you're missing that is important would be your PSU: Power Supply.  An old or damaged PSU could cause the problems you're experiencing as well.

Comment: @fbueckert it's not clogged with dust

Comment: What temperature does your CPU idle at?  That might hep give a baseline.

Comment: @fbueckert about 55 C

Comment: @tiddy I don't think it's PSU 'cause the +12 V rail is about 12.278

Comment: @fbueckert I now think it's heat because it's working at night better than day.But I already cleaned all the dust and i've put a thermal compound (a white paste that conducts heat) between the GPU and the fan.

Comment: @pixel it showed a BSOD today (check the question)

Comment: @fbueckert the GPU heats up to exactly 76 C when it's hanging but the CPU doesn't exceed 65 C

Comment: I had the same problem with my old PC. Turned out it was a broken disk drive.

Comment: According to Microsoft, your bluescreen indicates a [KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x8e--kernel-mode-exception-not-handled) error caused by a [memory access violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (a program trying to access RAM that it shouldn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns Out that the GPU has molten (Yet it was working !!!) , I replaced the GPU , then changed the MB and RAMs, games are now playing wonderfully and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

Some driver is failing. Disconnecting unnecessary hardware might get it to
run a bit longer, then let you add stuff back one at a time. Try unplugging all printers and things like that, close any background programs like MSN and uTorrent while you play games and see if that improves your situation.

If not you could strip out MSCONFIG and uninstall any applications you don't use anymore, so there is less running when you're playing games.

You could also try reinstalling Windows if you're certain this isn't a heat related problem, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I don't open background programs (else anti-virus of course) and I don't connect anything at usual.so your answer isn't what I expected.

Comment: @kalina - How can software ( a driver ) start to fail?

Comment: same as any software - file corruption, dependencies have changed, unhandled exceptions, etc... it's a pretty broad scope