# Blue screen of death while playing PES 2012?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2012

While playing PES 2012 suddenly after a goal all players turned black I paused the game after a minute or something the game started repeating the same par of sound then it showed a BSOD (blue screen of death).

My PC specs :

```
CPU                : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E4500 @ 2.20GHz
GPU                : Nvidia GeForce 7300 GS
GPU Driver version : 301.42
Ram                : 2 X 1GB
OS                 : Microsoft Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3 (build 2600)
Sound Card         : Realtek High Definition Audio
```

The BSOD :

[image: BSOD]

---

I've already searched for the error code , they tell me to turn off hardware acceleration but after I turn it off and restart every thing goes worse (Display driver not working, all games say that I have a 16MB video card)

So I enabled hardware acceleration again and now it's working just as it was.

I have also been advised to disable write combining (I don't know what is this) but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Got the exact same bug with my GPU, except it's an older one, and it crashes when i try to view flash videos... In my case, the problem was because the flash player managed to get the GPU memory out of bound... Only way to solve it was to downgrade the drivers... Did you had the problem before (with other games or other GPU drivers)? If your drivers aren't up to date, then upgrade them. If that's already the case, you could try downgrading them, to see if an older version would allow you to play.

Comment: If its a display error, did you try upgrading to the latest nVidia drivers? If that didn't work; try disabling antialiasing or shadows, and also check if playing in lower res works.

Comment: @Lysarion I already have the latest upgrade but there's a beta when i tried it ,it screwed everything up,I didn't have this before but I'm sure it's not a driver problem because it was the same driver all the time

Comment: @Alok there's not an option in PES 2012 to disable shadows or anti-aliasing but I can force disable them from Nvidia panel options, I'm already playing at 800*600

Comment: Hmm - find out the nVidia driver version and edit your answer to include that, might help get better replies

Comment: @Alok I added it 301.42 the beta one is 304.79

Comment: @Lysarion I'll try an older version of the driver (296.1) and I'll see if it solves this problem

Comment: Is that an AGP card? If yes, then try switching from AGP 8X to AGP 4X. That improved a lot of stability in my case.

Comment: @Bora yes it is but how do i do that?

Comment: @Lysarion the older versions didn't do any good

Comment: You must enter your mainboard BIOS during boot. Depending on mainboard, you need to press DEL, F1, F2, or some other key. See screen while booting. It should tell you something like "Press [KEY] to enter BIOS SETUP". Consult your mainboard manual, if you don't see it.

Comment: @Bora I'll try to find it

Comment: This is almost guaranteed the same issue as: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78692/nfs-world-crashes-and-pc-restarts-automatically

Comment: @fbueckert but the BSOD is different.

Comment: Both of these issues seem to involve overheating; have you resolved the issue for the other one?  If not, I'd bet it's the video card; try replacing it and see what happens.

Comment: I'm going to buy ATI Radeon HD 6450 2GB it sounds good I'll try it

Comment: @fbueckert I talked with Nvidia support and they told me that my card has been defected